# Не вся строка записывается в excel

Tags: python, openpyxl

Периодически при записи в файл excel, часть строки пропадает. С чем это может быть связано и как это можно обойти?

```
 import openpyxl

data=['e1cib/data/Справочник.ДокументыПредприятия?ref=047E0A66A8BC604EA677431DE7F504B7', 'e1cib/data/Справочник.ДокументыПредприятия?ref=047E0A66A8BC604EA677431DE7F504B7'] 

for count in range(1000):

 excel_file = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)

 excel_sheet = excel_file[sheet]

 excel_sheet.append(data)

 excel_file.save(file)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145585/discussion-on-question-by-dvgiv------excel); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась обновлением python и библиотеки:

1. python 3.9.13 → 3.11.3
2. openpyxl 3.0.10 →  3.1.2

Comment: И всё же очень странно. Я думаю это скорее вы в какой-то раз прервали процесс записи или ещё что-то такое сделали. Ну либо в библиотеках действительно был какой-то глюк.